# Dependency graph in Gradle projects

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

Is there a way to get the equivalent of Maven Dependency Graph but for Gradle projects in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate?

Comment: +1 to this quesiton. Answer from @Manu Viswam doesn't fully answer the quesiton. Maven Dependency Graph allows to see dependencies in  UML format, while gradle view doesn't. This is a really useful feature, and still don't understand why there isn't any equivalent for gradle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They released that feature on **2019.2**.

> To view Gradle dependencies as a diagram, click on the Show Dependencies icon on the Gradle tool window toolbar or use the shortcut Alt+Shift+Ctrl+U on Linux and Windows / Alt+Shift+Cmd+U on macOS.

https://blog.jetbrains.com/idea/2019/06/intellij-idea-2019-2-eap6-gradle-dependencies-diagram-and-more/

Answer (score 1):

May be very late to answer, but have you checked https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7150-gradle-view